# Repeating results Inner Join query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve data from 4 tables:

1. users_profile
2. friend_list
3. bs_items
4. bs.photos

I am trying to retrieve a product uploaded by friend of user and for that I made following query

```
select F.friend_id,F.status,F.uid, b.owner_id,b.price, b.currency, 
  b.item_name,b.item_id,bs.productId,bs.userId,bs.photo_thumb,u.uid,u.fname,
  u.lname, u.profile_pic 
from bs_items b,bs_photos bs,friend_list F,users_profile u 
where    F.status=1 and  F.uid='5' and U.uid=F.friend_id 
  and b.owner_id=F.friend_id 
  and b.item_id=bs.productId  and b.owner_id=bs.userId 
order by b.timestamp desc
```

But above query is giving me wanted result but its repeating them. for eg I have one friend who uploaded product then the record is fetch and its being repeated 5 times. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it may work for you.

```
select F.friend_id,F.status,F.uid, b.owner_id,b.price, b.currency,b.item_name,b.item_id,bs.productId,bs.userId,bs.photo_thumb,u.uid,u.fname,u.lname,u.profile_pic 
from users_profile u inner join friend_list F on u.uid=f.friend_id
Inner join bs_items b on b.owner_id=F.friend_id
inner join bs_photos bs on b.item_id=bs.productId 
where F.status=1 and F.uid='5' 
Group by F.uid
order by b.timestamp desc
```

Comment: it is repeating results . same prob friend

Comment: try now. i had made some changes

Comment: I used group by that's main diff. nyway nojoy :)

Comment: gosh never used joins before , hey can u help me with the same query without friends , ie get all products?

Comment: tell me what output you required?if u can put ur query then i will modify it according to your ans.

Comment: hey friend just noticed ur query is giving only one row result, but there are more then 3 rows which shoulkd come as a result?

Comment: if its like that just provide me your table structure i will modify it according to that

Comment: hey friend have no other option then taking some help fom u m stuck at this i dnt knw why its not working i was able to make the other query but this is not add me up in facebook